# tomcat + docker +java taking a lot of time to serve static page on initial load

Tags: java, docker, performance, tomcat, jvm-arguments

When I run a tomcat docker container to serve a war file, initial load takes a lot of time, after the first load, if I load the page even from incognito it loads immediately.

On first load
[image]

After first load:
[image]

docker stats output before first load:
[image]

docker stats output after first load:
[image]

I searched for solutions, they suggest to tweak `initialHeapSize`, `initialRamPercentage`, tried everything but it doesn't work.

Comment: Take thread dumps to see where the time is spent. A jsp page is not a static resource. By default, a JSP is converted to a servlet and is compiled at the first invocation. This could explain your response time.

Comment: keyword: `pre-compiling JSPs` (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)  / Web Application Compilation.

Comment: DNS resolution (failure/timeout) is often the cause of unexplained delays such as this. Server and application startup are sometimes delayed by random-number seeding blocking on entropy. A thread dump will prove whether or not either of these is the true cause.